# Default admin deleted. Cant access CLI on Palo Alto but have access to GUI

Tags: router, cli, palo-alto

I accidentally deleted the default admin for CLI on Palo Alto and now I can't log in. I have access to the GUI. I don't want to blow the image. Any ideas?

**What I have tried:**
I created a new superuser in the GUI but can't login to the CLI with the new user.

Comment: You did commit this new useraccount? Be default, as far as i understand, a superuser account can login with SSH/http/HTTPS